# Passing redux action to another component through TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have just finish following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3msLwu25SQY&list=PLk083BmAphjtGWyZUuo1BiCS_ZAgps6j5

Now I want to implement the TabNavigator which look like this

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { ActionCreators } from '../actions'
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import Home from './Home'

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    }
})

class AppContainer extends Component {

    render(){
        return <Tabs {...this.props}/>
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch)
}

export default connect((state) => { return {} }, mapDispatchToProps)(AppContainer)
```

However the redux action does not pass to the Home component and I got an error saying this.props.[actionname] is not a function.

Comment: `import { ActionCreators } from '../actions'` is probably the problem. Are you sure it's not supposed to be `import * as ActionCreators from '../actions'`? How are you exporting?

Comment: But it works fine before without the tabnavigator?

Answer (score 0):

show you my project

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{component: AppTabs}}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) =>
                    <route.component {...route.args} navigator={navigator} />
                }
            />
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

change the AppTabs to your Tabs, it maybe works.